# How can I return a dynamically allocated array and the size of the array then print it out through second function?

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic-arrays

I need to return a dynamically allocated array and the size of the array from a function then print it out through a second function.

I am having trouble with "const int *arr" and how to initialization it.

I added my code below. If there is anything else needed to better answer, please let me know.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// prototypes
int * generateAndFillArray(int & size);
void displayArray(const int *arr, int size);

int main()
{
    int size;
    const int arr;

    * generateAndFillArray(size);
    displayArray(&arr, size);

    return 0;
}

//Prompt the User for a number (1-10) then dynamically allocate an array of this size.
//Prompt the user to fill out the array, with numbers (1-100) all numbers included (1 and 100 are allowed).
//Return the array through the return statement to the main body and the size of the array through a reference parameter.

int * generateAndFillArray(int &size) {
    cout << "Enter a number (1-10) that will serve as the size of the array: ";
    cin >> size;
    while (!(size >= 1 && size <= 10))
    {
        cout << "Please enter a correct number between 1 and 10. ";
        cin >> size;
    }

    int *arr;
    arr = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << "enter a number for each subscript of the array ";
        cin >> arr[i];
        cout << "you entered " << arr[i] << endl;
    }

    return &size;
}

//Display on one line, by itself, with a space following each number, surrounded by square
//    brackets. example: [1 59 13 37 55]
void displayArray(const int *numbers, int size) {

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << *(numbers) << "  ";
    }
}
```

I am unable to change the prototypes. I am requesting assistance with a project for school.

With that being said, this only covers about 10% of the project. I am not requesting anyone do my homework for me. Only looking for help with a small section.

Comment: What you should be doing is to use `std::vector<int>` instead of a `int[]`.

Comment: you call `displayArray` passing a pointer to an int, and the function name, parameter name, argument name and function code makes me think you want to pass an array as parameter. There is also a memory leak ( you allocate at : `int *arr; arr = new int[size];`, but you don't delete it or return it ). Also, why do you return the pointer to the argument that will be modified anyway when you pass it as a non const reference ? Don't you want to return the array itself ? Why don't you assign the return value when you call `generateAndFillArray` ? You just dereference it

Comment: When passing arrays to functions, you should pass the capacity also.

Comment: `int size; const int arr; * generateAndFillArray(size);` --> `int size; int *arr = generateAndFillArray(size);` and in `generateAndFillArray`: `return &size;` --> `return arr;`. You need to study the difference between pointers and references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with the code, namely

- the code in `main()` is just completely wrong.  You are declaring `arr` as `const` without initializing it, and you are not declaring it as a pointer at all. You are passing `arr` to `displayArray()` using `operator&`, which you don't need if `arr` were a pointer to begin with.  And you are not calling `delete[]` to free the array that `generateAndFillArray()` allocates with `new[]`.
- in `generateAndFillArray()`, you are not validating to make sure that the user is entering actual numbers at all, you are only validating that numbers are in a given range.  If the user types a non-number value, `operator>>` fails, but you are not checking for that.  You are also not returning the pointer to the allocated array.
- in `displayArray()`, you are not outputting the array in the format that you have documented. Even if you were, you are only outputting the 1st number in the array on each loop iteration.  You are not actually looping through the whole array.

Try something more like this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

// prototypes
int* generateAndFillArray(int & size);
void displayArray(const int *arr, int size);

int main()
{
    int size;
    int *arr = generateAndFillArray(size);
    displayArray(arr, size);
    delete[] arr;

    return 0;
}

//Prompt the User for a number (1-10) then dynamically allocate an array of this size.
//Prompt the user to fill out the array, with numbers (1-100) all numbers included (1 and 100 are allowed).
//Return the array through the return statement to the main body and the size of the array through a reference parameter.

int* generateAndFillArray(int &size)
{
    cout << "Enter a number (1-10) that will serve as the size of the array: ";
    do
    {
        if (cin >> size)
        {
            if (size >= 1 && size <= 10)
                break;

            cout << "Please enter a correct number between 1 and 10. ";
        }
        else
        {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            cout << "Please enter a valid number between 1 and 10. ";
        }
    }
    while (true);

    int *arr = new int[size];

    cout << "enter a number for each subscript of the array ";

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        while (!(cin >> arr[i]))
        {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            cout << "Please enter valid numbers for subscript " << i << " onward. ";
        }
    }

    return arr;
}

//Display on one line, by itself, with a space following each number, surrounded by square
//    brackets. example: [1 59 13 37 55]
void displayArray(const int *numbers, int size)
{
    cout << "[";
    if (size > 0)
    {
        cout << numbers[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
            cout << " " << numbers[i];
    }
    cout << "]" << endl;
}
```

That being said, you really should be using `std::vector` instead of `new[]` directly.  And you can use STL algorithms like [`std::copy_n()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n) instead of manual input/output loops:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

// prototypes
vector<int> generateAndFillArray();
void displayArray(const vector<int> &arr);

int main()
{
    vector<int> arr = generateAndFillArray();
    displayArray(arr);
    return 0;
}

//Prompt the User for a number (1-10) then dynamically allocate an array of this size.
//Prompt the user to fill out the array, with numbers (1-100) all numbers included (1 and 100 are allowed).
//Return the array through the return statement to the main body.

vector<int> generateAndFillArray()
{
    int size;
    cout << "Enter a number (1-10) that will serve as the size of the array: ";
    do
    {
        if (cin >> size)
        {
            if (size >= 1 && size <= 10)
                break;

            cout << "Please enter a correct number between 1 and 10. ";
        }
        else
        {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            cout << "Please enter a valid number between 1 and 10. ";
        }
    }
    while (true);

    vector<int> arr;
    arr.reserve(size);

    cout << "enter a number for each subscript of the array ";

    do
    {
        copy_n(istream_iterator<int>(cin), size, back_inserter(arr));
        if (cin)
            break;

        arr.clear();
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cout << "enter valid numbers for each subscript of the array ";
    }
    while (true);

    return arr;
}

//Display on one line, by itself, with a space following each number, surrounded by square
//    brackets. example: [1 59 13 37 55]
void displayArray(const vector<int> &numbers)
{
    cout << "[";
    copy_n(numbers.begin(), numbers.size(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
    cout << "]" << endl;
}
```